# Automate navigation through a GUI program

Tags: windows, powershell, gui

I have a GUI program which is the in-between for a repetitive task. Is there a way to navigate through the program and click the desired items in the menu bar to automate the task (it also has to navigate through a save file menu)?

I know Powershell scripting, and I've been using it automate the other parts of the task, but the particular program I'm using doesn't have command-line parameters to navigate through it.

Comment: Google for the program `Autohotkey`. Alternatively `AutoIt`. Both will allow you to script application automation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mokubai stated in the comments. AutoHotkey and AutoIt are both great applications for automating Windows. AutoHotkey was derived from AutoIt, but they have become significantly different from each-other over the years. You can obtain the same results with both of them.

Use **AutoHotkey** if you want to **setup hotkeys or string expansions**. I.E. Press button or key combination to perform scripted action.

Use **AutoIt** if you for example want it to **fully automate install processes**. 
*(I personally would still use AutoHotkey for this, but that's just my preference.)*

---

AutoHotkey Website
https://autohotkey.com/

AutoHotkey Documentation
https://autohotkey.com/docs/AutoHotkey.htm

AutoIt Website
https://www.autoitscript.com

AutoIt Documentation 
https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/

---

Both AutoHotkey and AutoIt are extensively documented and have very active scripting communities and you can find plenty of help on either of their forums.

Check out the AutoHotkey scripting showcase for a small taste of what it can do. 
https://autohotkey.com/docs/scripts/index.htm

Also check out the AutoHotkey Scripts and Functions forum. https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewforum.php?f=6

AutoIt also has a forum dedicated to example scripts that is worth a look.
https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/forum/9-autoit-example-scripts/

Answer (score 1):

Besides the suggestions already listed, you may also wish to investigate [PyAutoGUI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyAutoGUI). It requires [Python for Windows](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/), but comes with features that allow it to potentially automate most interfaces. Python itself is a powerful yet generally easy to use scripting language, which may be useful as well.